# How do clients and DLLs are compatible with respect to calling convnetion

Tags: dll, com, compatibility, calling-convention

Let's consider the following simple scenario:

```
// Library.dll

void Foo()
{
 // some code
}


// main.c/cpp
int main()
{
    //  ...
    Foo();
    // ...
}
```

**First:**
From what i know, the caller and the callee must work with the same calling convention. And 
if there is a full hand of calling conventions, how is it that we can just link
`main.cpp` with the `Library.dll` 
and call `Foo`?

What guarantees that the caller and callee in this case uses the same calling convention?

Is this part of  the problems that the COM architecture is trying to solve?

**Second:** I know there's a way to specify the type of calling convention 
when declaring/defining a function. Is there a way to specify 
a calling convention to the caller as well?

## Clarifiaction

Maybe the question wasn't clear enough. 
The question refers to a scenario in which the library was 
compiled by some other developer, by an arbitrary compiler. 
I compile my own `main.cpp` with my arbitrary compiler. 
How can i be sure that both our compilers "Speak the same language" 
with respect to calling conventions?

Comment: You, the author of the code, guarantee that the caller and the callee use the same calling convention. The compiler doesn't just pick a calling convention for a function by a random coin toss - it's determined by the source code and the build settings, all of which you control. I suppose I don't fully understand the thrust of your question.

Comment: If the calling convention is specified in the function declaration, then the caller would use that convention when calling that function. Calling convention is part of the function signature, along with the number and types of parameters. (If the convention is not explicitly specified, the default one is used, determined by compiler options).

Comment: COM does require that all interface methods use stdcall calling convention (in 32-bit code; there's only one calling convention for 64-bit code, so the problem fails to arise). But that's not what COM is primarily about; it's just one minor part of the spec.

Comment: Sure, COM solves it by dictating the convention to stdcall.  Not what you're doing here, it is now the name decoration that ensures there is a match.  cdecl  produces `_Foo`, stdcall produces `_Foo@0` and thiscall/C++ yields `?Foo@@YAXXZ`.  So you'll get a linker error on a mismatch.